# making a particular part of a page an editable region in dreamweaver cs6

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I have a template withe several divs. now, i am confused on how to make a particular part editable and append it to another existing page.

E.g. I have a page which has been developed, I want to make the menu navigation, right bar, and footer menu editable such that i can append it to the already created page.

I have created an editable page, but its just adding the whole page to the new page making it look jam-packed.

How can i go about this?

Any help with steps will be appreciated

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could put your html into a php file, and then create the file that you want to append the code to a php file as well. then all you have to do is put:

```
<?php
include 'filename';
?>
```

Wherever you want the code to appear on the page.

Note, all html works in a php file as long as the html is not surrounded by the php tags.

For example you could do this

```
<html>
<title> Hello </title>
....other html here.....

    <?php
    include 'filename';
    ?>
</html>
```

But this wont work:

Hello 
    ....other html here.....


        include 'filename';

    

?>

Comment: Hello @trevor, thank you for this insight. it never occured to me. I will placed them in a php include filename.. Thanks !

Comment: If this helped you in any way please upvote, also if you feel this is the best answer please press the checkmark beside my answer! Thanks a ton!